# Exporting specific MySQL data from table to Excel using Python

Tags: python, mysql, excel, csv, export

I'm fairly new to mysql-connector-python. I'm in the middle of learning how to use python to make my job a little easier. Could you please help?

I have a database with one table.Lets call it ‘table1’ The table is broken down with columns like this:

`sent_time | delivered_time |id1_active |id2_active |id3_active |id1_inactive |id2_inactive |id3_inactive |location_active |location_inactive` …..`lots more

Lets say that these are two or more customers delivering goods to and from each other. Each customer has three id#s.

Right now I want to see if I can at least print out id1_active and id2_active for all of them…ideally, I want to print the entire rows with a specific id mentioned in any of the columns…can you look below and see what I’m doing wrong and maybe help me figure out a solution for my ideal goal?

I keep getting this error

> line 18, in 
>       c.writerow([id1_active,id2_active] )
>
> TypeError: ‘str’ does not support the buffer interface

This is what I have thus far…

I created a ‘config.ini’ file to make my life a bit easier

```
[mysql]
host = localhost
database = db_name
user = root
password = blahblah
```

I created a ‘python_mysql_dbconfig.py’

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def read_db_config(filename=’config.ini’, section=’mysql’):
“”” Read database configuration file and return a dictionary object
:param filename: name of the configuration file
:param section: section of database configuration
:return: a dictionary of database parameters
“””
# create parser and read ini configuration file
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read(filename)

# get section, default to mysql
db = {}
if parser.has_section(section):
items = parser.items(section)
for item in items:
db[item[0]] = item[1]
else:
raise Exception(‘{0} not found in the {1} file’.format(section, filename))

return db
```

Then I created ‘export.py’

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
import csv

filename=open(‘test.csv’,’wb’)
c=csv.writer(filename)

db_config = read_db_config()
conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = (“SELECT id1_active, id2_active from table1”)

cursor.execute(query)

for id1_active, id2_active in cursor:
c.writerow([id1_active,id2_active] )

cursor.close()
filename.close()
cnn.close()
```

Could you tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the data and loop through data instead of cursor:

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
import csv

filename=open(‘test.csv’,’wb’)
c=csv.writer(filename)

db_config = read_db_config()
conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = (“SELECT id1_active, id2_active from table1”)

cursor.execute(query)

#You first need to fetch data
data = cursor.fetchall()
for item in data:
    c.writerow(item )

cursor.close()
filename.close()
cnn.close()
```

Comment: I started messing with xlsxwriter and actually got further on my own...could you look at my code and see why I cannot select data to be exported between two datetimes?

Answer (score 1):

I started figuring things out using xlswriter. I was able to export all data from the table but now I cannot get my code to pull the data that falls between two datetimes....it keeps telling me

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\timerange.py", line 36, in <module>
    start_date = datetime.datetime(userIn,timeShape)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Please, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
# Establish a MySQL connection
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
db_config = read_db_config()
conn = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
cursor = conn.cursor()

#creates the workbook
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('imhere.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

#formatting definitions
bold    = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'})
timeShape =  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'



query = ("SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, customer_name, id1_active, id2_active, id3_active, id1_inactive, id2_inactive, id3_inactive, location_active, location_inactive FROM table1 ")
"WHERE sent_time BETWEEN %s AND %s"
userIn = input("Type Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss):")
userEnd = input("Type End Date (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss):")
start_date = datetime.datetime(userIn,timeShape)
end_date = datetime.datetime(userEnd, timeShape)



# Execute sql Query
cursor.execute(query, (start_date, end_date))
#result = cursor.fetchall()


#sets up the header row
worksheet.write('A1','sent_time',bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'delivered_time',bold)
worksheet.write('C1', 'customer_name',bold)
worksheet.write('D1', 'id1_active',bold)
worksheet.write('E1', 'id2_active',bold)
worksheet.write('F1', 'id3_active',bold)
worksheet.write('G1', 'id1_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('H1', 'id2_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('I1', 'id3_inactive',bold)
worksheet.write('J1', 'location_active',bold)
worksheet.write('K1', 'location_inactive',bold)
worksheet.autofilter('A1:K1')



print("sent_time", "delivered_time", "customer_name", "id1_active", "id2_active", "id3_active", "id1_inactive", "id2_inactive", "id3_inactive", "location_active", "location_inactive")
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9],row[10])

# Create a For loop to iterate through each row in the XLS file, starting at row 2 to skip the headers
for r, row in enumerate(cursor, start=1):  #where you want to start printing results inside workbook
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,0,row[0], date_format)
        worksheet.write_datetime(r,1, row[1], date_format)
        worksheet.write(r,2, row[2])
        worksheet.write(r,3, row[3])
        worksheet.write(r,4, row[4])
        worksheet.write(r,5, row[5])
        worksheet.write(r,6, row[6])
        worksheet.write(r,7, row[7])
        worksheet.write(r,8, row[8])
        worksheet.write(r,9, row[9])
        worksheet.write(r,10, row[10])




#close out everything and save
cursor.close()
workbook.close()
conn.close()

#print number of rows and bye-bye message
print ("- - - - - - - - - - - - -")
rows = len(result)
print ("I just imported "+ str(rows) + " rows from MySQL!")
print ("")
print ("Good to Go!!!")
print ("")
```